# Getting typeahead working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

This might be a silly question but I'm having issues getting twitter's typeahead to work.

From the working tutorial [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), I copied the code into a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eq4p8/) with bootstrap and typeahead.

I'm just working with a simple text field:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
```

Comment: you are missing element `#the-basics` which got CSS applied + the fiddle didn't have jquery included, see http://jsfiddle.net/eq4p8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tutorial, we need a wrapper `div` for the input, which will get CSS applied and get DOM elements created within.

On declaration we have:

```
$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}
```

Meaning our wrapper will be `#the-basics` as done in tutorial, we need to add the wrapper around:

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
```

as:

```
<div id="the-basics">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA" />
</div>
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/eq4p8/1/

Comment: Thanks so much! I know it had to be something simple I was missing!